# Jquery. Как с помощью класса переписать стили у элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть обыкновенный блок **div**, у которого **background-color** черный. На этот блок повешен обработчик события **click**, который добавляет класс(**.red**) нашему блоку и меняет(по идеи) **background-color** на красный. Но так как наш блок уже имеет css свойство **background-color**, то новоприбывший класс отказывается переписывать его своим значением.

```js
$('.black').click(function (event) {
    elem = $(this);
    $(elem).toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
.black {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="black"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, либо `!important`, либо селектор поселективнее...

Comment: @vp_arth либо селектор поселективнее???

Comment: `.right_panel .the_portal.red{...}`,  например

Comment: @vp_arth **background-color: red !important;**  ПОМОГ!

Comment: Спасибо Большое =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую прочитать замечательную [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/137588/) про вес селекторов. Касательно конкретно вашей задачи - можно: 
1)Добавлять не класс, а свойство с помощью метода `css`.
2)Добавить в вашем классе !important.

Comment: есть золотое правило, что может быть следано в css, должно быть сделано в  css,  а менять правло методом css, если тольео какой то крайний случай...  просто надо было  селекторы правильно прописывать .black.red{} и даже  !important не нужен

Comment: @Air А можете по подробнее описать ваше решение

Comment: Denis, это не решение, а мнение...   И что именно в подробностях хотелось бы тебе услышать? Можно на ТЫ, легче общаться... И мне не совсем понятно, почему ты решил, что переназначенное не является его стилем, и на кой надо, чтобы именно переназначить его, это имеет принципиальный момент?  Чтобы переназначить полностью надо прописывать полностью оба селектора и все  стили и тогда будет так как тебе надо...

Comment: просто  !important может в определенный момент помешать, когда кода будет с километр, и где то там надо будет, что-то менять... Потом ищи где да что...   Опять прописывать  !important? Это не верное решение